# Stopping SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I've tried googling for help, but it is not as easy as you would have imagined.  If someone could just tell me how to secure the SQL, or even give me a link to a good website to learn how to do it myself.

If you could even be kind enough to fix it, and tell me what was wrong, I will definitely take note, and secure the rest of my code.

```
    <?php
    $post = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tool WHERE id = $post");
    $authorr = $_SESSION['Username'];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
 $capsd = ucfirst($author);
 $title= $row['title'];
 $details= $row['details'];
 $author= $row['author'];
 $date= $row['date'];
 $img= $row['featuredimage'];
 $id= $row['id'];



    echo "<table border=1><tr><td width=100px>
                 <b><u><center>";
    echo $title;
    echo "</center></u></td> <td width=100px><center>";
    echo $date;
    echo "</center></td> <td width=100px><b><center>";
    echo ucfirst($author);
    echo "</center></b></td>";

    if (in_array($authorr, $allowedposters)) {
    echo "<center><td width=20px><a href=edit.php?id=";
    echo $id;
    echo "><b>Edit</b></a></center></td>";
    }
   echo "</tr></table>";
   echo "<img src=http://www.removed.com/news/";
   echo $img;
   echo " height=300 width=400> <br><br>";
   echo $details;

   }
   ?>
```

Comment: In this specific case the only injection risk is on putting `$post` to SQL query. Since it is integer value, it's enough to get it like this: `$post = intval($_GET["id"]);`. `intval` is guaranteed to return valid integer (0 if there is none in the passed string). It can't contain any SQL injections so it's secure. And it can't contain any HTML code, so `htmlspecialchars` call becomes unnecessary. Note that `$title`, `$date` etc. values must be processed with `htmlspecialchars` if they can store some HTML code inputed by user. Otherwise it's XSS risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Essentially, the answer is to use prepared statements and sanitize your input.